# Can I design a mongo collection which will be updated by many clients?

Tags: mongodb

Please see my questions very carefully, thanks.

I designed a collection to store monitor information. The data stored in the collection will be like below:

```
{
    metric_name: 'physical_memory_used',
    server_name: 'server_a',
    time: timestamp,
    value: 2000
    tag1: value1,
    tag2: value2,
    ...
}
```

**metric_name** is the name of the monitored items like 'physical_memory_used', 'process_count' .. . This is an mandatory field for every document.

**server_name** indicate which server did this data comes from. So it is also a mandatory field.

**time** stores  the timestamp when the data collected. Also mandatory. But the value of this fields will change frequently. Because I only store the latest data, and I store them every 5 seconds.

**value** store the collected value for this monitored item so also mandatory. And it also change very frequently. same reason as the time filed.

Other fields like tag1:value1, tag2:value2 is not mandatory. Because different monitored items may have different attributes. For example: NIC may have a tag:value pair like 'nic_name:eth0' to indicate the nic name.

I create a index on

```
metric_name
server_name
```

since this two are the mandatory fields (which means every document have them) and the are not updated frequently like time and value field.

**This index is not a unique index since one metric of one server may have multiple documents. For example: The metric nic_io_per_seconds for one server may generate several documents since there may be multiple nics. We use tag:value pairs like nic_name=eth0 to seperate them**

Now below are my concern

```
The collection may be update thousands of servers each seconds.

I will have another system querying the collection every seconds.
```

The update and query will always use the index i created.

Is this a bad design?

I did a few search and study, think it is ok. Because although the collection will be updated tens of thousands of time every seconds. these updates will be happened on different documents. (different server, different monitored items) so no competition. Also the indexed columns "metric_name", "server_name" will always remain the same value, the are not updated. So should not cause any update on index, so it should be OK.

Regarding the search. although the collection may be very big. but though the index (metric_name, server)we can always get a very little data set.  so performance should be OK

The above are only my guess. I am not sure so ask here. Please give some advice if you have

Comment: Sounds about right to me. I would consider using `metric_name` and `server_name` as a compound `_id` field like this: `_id: { metric_name: "something", server_name: "something" }` as this will guarantee uniqueness and also reduce the number of indexes MongoDB needs to maintain. With respect to performance: You'll need to implement this, then measure and then optimize. Anything else is just "finger in the air" kind of guesswork.

Comment: @dnickless Wrong. With `_id: { metric_name: "something", server_name: "something" }`, each server can write exact one doc per metric. And it absolutely makes sense to do theoretically correct modelling. Measuring what your setup can take then gives an idea about the scaling factor.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: The OP said he would "only store the latest data" so that should be ok - in fact it would help to ensure he really does only store a single set of information which is where my suggestion was coming from.

Comment: @dnickless Nope. Because after the first data set written, all else would error. An update or upsert should be prevented, as this requires a lookup and a write instead of a write. And latest could also well mean "latest 24h/week";) Using low cardinality fields as `_id` is a Very Bad Idea™. They make great shard keys, though.

Comment: Are those servers all yours or can there be multiple clients? Are we talking of geographical distributed servers to monitor?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Yes, of course, he'd have to use an upsert. The thing is: If he only wants the latest data, there's no way he gets around the lookup and write.

Comment: @dnickless MongoDB is the wrong tool for storing only a couple of megabytes, anyway.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Agreed but to my understanding he's expecting large collections (tons of servers but only one data point per server/metric combination). Whatever. Pretty broad question anyway...